# Using quotation marks in ModelBuilder of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, error-999999, error-000210

The syntax in the ModelBuilder of ArcMap varies when trying to use the 'Name' output.

When do I use double quotes, single quotes, or no quotes?

Answer (score 1):

If you get the error that:

> The calculated value is invalid for the row with ObjectID = 1.

It means you've tried to use %Name% in a calculate field--tou need to use "%Name%" with the double-quotes.  It may also mean you've used "%Name%" appropriately, but are trying to calculate a non-text (string) field. ArcMap will repeatedly ask if you wish to abort or continue, as it tries to calculate for each field.

In contrast:

> General error executing calculator. ERROR 999999: Error executing
> function. Syntax error Failed to execute (Calculate Field).

Means you've used single quotes: '%Name%'.

**File Naming**

> ERROR 000210: Cannot create output N:\MA\MA_Documents\MA_Proj\NCHRP_PPP\Atlanta\Aug23.gdb\SS_"fishnet5b_I85_vmt"

Means you tried to use double quotes in a file name. Using single quotes will generate the same error.